# how to echo "on" or "off" text only?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

Everyone knows, that in Windows command file (`.cmd`)

```
echo on
echo off
```

enables and disables echo. But how to echo only text "on" or text "off"? I.e. how to send text

```
on
off
```

to `stdout`?
Target system: Windows XP.
And what about making it in DOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
C:\> echo.on
on
C:\> echo.off
off
```

This actually works with a number of different characters, including but possibly not limited to:

`/`, `\`, `,`, `:`, `;`, `(`.

According to [this thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) on dostips.com, it's actually best (most robust) to use:

```
echo(on
```

As the other characters have obscure situations in which they can fail (e.g. a file named `echo` exists on `%PATH%`).

Comment: Which chars may be also used instead of dot?

Comment: At least `/`, `:`, `,`, and backslash - I don't know of any official documentation on this, unfortunately.

Comment: You should also be able to use `(`

Comment: @SomethingDark yep, seems to work - but `)` doesn't. Also, `;` works.

Comment: There was an entire topic about this on DosTips a while ago. They ultimately came to the conclusion that `echo(` was the best way to display text and `echo/` was the best way to print blank lines.

Comment: @SomethingDark Do you have a link? I always thought `echo.` was the "official" way to print  a blank line..

Comment: @Blorgbeard - They are all hacks - there is no "official" method. `echo.` is certainly more traditional, but there are obscure situations where that can fail. In fact, the only variant that never fails is `echo(`. All other variants have at least one situation where it can fail. Here is one link that gives some of the info: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774

Comment: Thanks guys, incorporated that info into the answer.

Comment: I usually use `echo/any text` in all situations when the output text is known and only use `echo(%variable%` when the value of `variable` may be one of the few cases that `echo/` can not handle, like `set "variable=/?"`