# Windows echo command: The odds of cmd.exe escaping

Tags: windows, cmd, escaping, echo

I'm in the unfortunate position to be forced to invoke a program via `echo <input> | program.exe`. Of course, I wondered how to escape `<input>` and found:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)
- [Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt/)

In essence, it seems sufficient to escape all special chars with `^`. Out of curiosity I still would like to know, why echo ingores double-quote escaping in the first place:

```
C:\>echo "foo"
"foo"

C:\>
```

Is there any normative reference?

Bonus question: How to echo the strings `on` and `off` with the echo command?

Edit: I just found [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772462(v=ws.11).aspx). I states that only `|<>` need to be escaped. However, expansion like `%FOO%` still work.

Comment: for the Bonus: `echo/on` and `echo/off` (note: no space after `echo`) (same method is used to `echo` a possibly empty variable without getting "ECHO is on": `echo/%emty%`. There are some charactes, you can use instead of `/` (best is `(`, but it can be confusing to read). There is a very good explanation about that somewhere. I'll try to find it again...

Comment: This is funny indeed. The doc I found states `.` as the character to be used. `,;:` work as well.

Comment: [found it](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774&hilit=echo+blank+line) In short: `(` seems odd but is the most reliable one.

Comment: Quote marks appear fairly frequently in English.  It would be inconvenient if `echo` treated them as special characters.

Comment: it's not only `|<>`, but also `&^` and in some cases even `)%`

Comment: @HarryJohnston That is plausible, of course. However, it ramifies the shell syntax by applying different escaping rules for special built-in commands.

Comment: Not exactly; shell characters that are inside quote marks are always ignored, and that's all the shell itself does.  It is up to each individual command (regardless of whether it is an internal or external command) to decide what, if anything, the quote marks mean.

Comment: ECHO isn't the only internal command that treats quotes as normal characters; SET, for example, includes them in values. That is, `set var="value"` would store the quotes as part of the value of the variable. Also, this SO answer is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37911799/2712565

Answer (score 1):

Special characters like `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `%`, `!` and `"` may cause problems with `echo`, also when trying to `echo` a string into a pipe; odd numbers of `"` are particularly difficult to handle.

Building escape sequences can be very complicated particularly with pipes, because such initiates new `cmd` instances for either side, so multi-escaping might become necessary.

The only reliable way to pipe the output of `echo` into a program is to use a variable holding the string to return and to apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), but within the left side of the pipe, like this:

```cmd
cmd /V /C echo(^^!VARIABLE^^!| program.exe
```

Note the double-escaping of `!` like `^^!`, which makes this code even work when delayed expansion is also enabled in the parent `cmd` instance. There must not be a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of the `|`, because this was echoed too otherwise. Note that `echo` terminates the output by a line-break.